# Dynamic Height of TableView in a ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How can I set the height of a table view as variable or dynamic ? For example when I have more cells then the tableview should be bigger and I can't do it with a fix height.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] to improve your question and provide a [example] describing what you have already tried and what your exact problem is.

Comment: Try to provide more detail to explain what you are trying to do. Table views are designed to scroll their rows... why would you be putting a table view in a scroll view, and then trying to change the height of the table view?

Comment: Because I want to have multiple tableviews in one view and I only want to show them when the user press a view.